# How can I add/replace a command to the end of an SSH public key from script?

Tags: linux, perl, awk, ssh, sed

When restricting which commands an SSH public key may give access to, one would add `command="something"` at the end of the SSH public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

In my case, I want to write a Bash script that creates [Borg repositories](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment/central-backup-server.html#), and each public key needs to have a restriction such as this

```
command="cd /home/backup/repos/<client fqdn>;
         borg serve --restrict-to-path /home/backup/repos/<client fqdn>",
         restrict <keytype> <key> <host>
```

**Question**

Is there an official way to do this instead of writing an `awk` or `sed` one-liner?

Or is there just an `awk` or `sed` solution that is so beautiful, that there isn't a need to an official supported way?

Comment: If one exists, please show an example of a relevant ***in***_"elegant `awk` or `sed` one-liner"_.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Slurp;
my $fqdn = $ARGV[0];
my $k = read_file("$ARGV[1]");
my @m = split / /, $k;
my $c = 'command="cd /tank/borg/repos/FQDN; borg serve --restrict-to-path /tank/borg/repos/FQDN",restrict TYPE KEY';

$c =~ s/FQDN/$fqdn/g;
$c =~ s/TYPE/$m[0]/g;
$c =~ s/KEY/$m[1]/g;

print $c;
```

Forced commands are first in the file, not last.